# Sequelize: Query with order by a field in JSONB object

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize v3.30.4. I am unable to query with an order by a field in a nested JSONB object. This column in User I am calling `payload` which has a field of `priority`. I am using the postgres dialect. I am wondering how you would do this without using a SQL raw query and without a raw query if possible. I've tried all these commented ways and am wanting to set order along with the other 2 rules you see:

```
function getUsers (id, req, res) {
  const sequelize = req.app.context.sequelize;
  const User = sequelize.model('user');
  const Post = sequelize.model('post');
  const Tag = sequelize.model('tag');

  return User.findOne({
    where: { id },
    include: [
     Post,
      Tag
    ],
    order: [
      // ['payload.priority'],
      // [sequelize.json('users.payload.priority', 'ASC')],
      // [User.payload.priority],
      // [User.payload, 'priority', 'ASC'],
      // [User, 'payload', 'priority', 'ASC'],
      // ['payload', 'priority', 'ASC'],
      // ['payload', 'priority'],
      [Post, 'rank'],
      [Tag, 'rank']
    ]
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 4):

you can just use it in the following way

```
    function getUsers (id, req, res) {
  const sequelize = req.app.context.sequelize;
  const User = sequelize.model('user');
  const Post = sequelize.model('post');
  const Tag = sequelize.model('tag');

  return User.findOne({
    where: { id },
    include: [
     Post,
      Tag
    ],
    order: [
      ['payload.priority','asc']
    ]
})
```

i am using sequelize version 4.33.0 and it is working fine for me
this is the link for the merged request
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/7565/files/b5d77ecedbe96d47d053cb9f11e10cdf0f84d0ae

let know in case of any queries,happy coding :)