# Sequelize: Query with order by a field in JSONB object as number

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have looked into [Sequelize: Query with order by a field in JSONB object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213802/sequelize-query-with-order-by-a-field-in-jsonb-object) but still have some bug.

when I sort the query by the json field which have number in it, it will sort it as string, and result will be

```
1
11
111
2
22
222
3
33
333
```

Is there any way to sort the query by json field as number like below?

```
1
2
3
11
22
33
111
222
333
```

The code I use is like:

```
models.findAll({
    order:[
        ['json.a','DESC']
    ]
});
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you share some data and table definition

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the query you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast your extracted data using `CAST`

```
select json_id
from mytable
order by CAST ( json_id AS integer )
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/8igKthLG)